# merging 2 xml records with the same schema

Tags: c#, .net, xml

**How do we merge 2 XML records that have the same schema?**

For example let's say we have two records such as :

```
<msg>
<name>alex</name>
<payload></payload>
</msg>
```

and the second:

```
<msg>
<name></name>
<payload>blabla</payload>
</msg>
```

The expected result:

```
<msg>
<name>alex</name>
<payload>blabla</payload>
</msg>
```

We simply took the non-empty value.

**How do we merge two xml records with the same schema?**

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation would just go though the elements pairing corresponding items by name and create a new element choosing the text of the non-blank element.

```
XElement ShallowMerge(XElement a, XElement b) =>
    new XElement(a.Name,
        from ae in a.Elements()
        join be in b.Elements() on ae.Name equals be.Name
        select new XElement(ae.Name,
            !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)ae)
                ? (string)ae
                : (string)be
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //two lists for temp storing .xml data

    List<Person> list1= new List<Person>();
    List<Person> list2= new List<Person>();

    List<Person> list3= new List<Person>();//for mixing
    string path=@"c:\.....";


    //properties of .xml notes like 'name' and 'payload'
    public class Person
    {
      public string name{ get; set; }//1
      public string payload{ get; set; }//2
    }  


   //load both .xml files saperatly
    void load_list1()
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(path + @"\list1.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode xnode in xdoc.SelectNodes("Items/Item"))
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.name= xnode.SelectSingleNode("a").InnerText;
            p.payload= xnode.SelectSingleNode("b").InnerText;
            list1.Items.Add(p);
        }
    }

    void load_list2()
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(path + @"\list2.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode xnode in xdoc.SelectNodes("Items/Item"))
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.name= xnode.SelectSingleNode("a").InnerText;
            p.payload= xnode.SelectSingleNode("b").InnerText;
            list2.Items.Add(p);
        }
    }


   //start mixing both lists
   void mixdata()
   {
     for(int i=0;i<list1.Items.Count;i++)
     {
       Person p= new Person();
       p.name=list1.Items[i].name;
       p.payload=list2.Items[i].payload;
       list3.Items.Add(p);         
     }
   }

    //saving final mixed list to .xml
    void save()
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(path + @"\Mixed_data.xml");
        XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Items");
        xnode.RemoveAll();

        foreach (Person i in list3)
        {
            XmlNode xtop = xdoc.CreateElement("Item");

            XmlNode x1 = xdoc.CreateElement("a");
            XmlNode x2 = xdoc.CreateElement("b");

            x1.InnerText = i.name;
            x2.InnerText = i.payload;

            xtop.AppendChild(x1);
            xtop.AppendChild(x2);

            xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xtop);
        }
        xdoc.Save(path + @"\data.xml");
    }
    //let me know any errors
```